# Encryption/decryption of sound file Blackberry application

Tags: blackberry, encryption

I need a help regarding sound file encryption/decryption. I would like to encrypt a sound file while I store this and decrypt same while play this file. I read about encryption/decryption in java and lots of sample code available for this in java. but these programs doesn't work with blackberry. My requirement is for blackberry application. Anybody have any link or sample code to encryption/decryption please provide me

Regards
Vaibhav Singh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Using basic encryption with BlackBerry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Use-Basic-Encryption/ta-p/445092)

[Using advanced encryption with BlackBerry](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Use-Advanced-Encryption/ta-p/445085)

[BlackBerry encryption and decryption lab tutorial](http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/Basic-Encryption-and-Decryption/ta-p/442782)